How do I programatically create a new Subscription?
I'm writing a GoLang application that creates a new Azure Subscription programatically. I'm using the Azure SDK for Go.
Here is sample code I found to do something similar:
    clientFactory, err := armapimanagement.NewClientFactory("<subscription-id>", cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    res, err := clientFactory.NewSubscriptionClient().CreateOrUpdate(ctx, "rg1", "apimService1", "testsub", armapimanagement.SubscriptionCreateParameters{
        Properties: &armapimanagement.SubscriptionCreateParameterProperties{
            DisplayName: to.Ptr("testsub"),
            OwnerID:     to.Ptr("/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/users/57127d485157a511ace86ae7"),
            Scope:       to.Ptr("/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/products/5600b59475ff190048060002"),
        },
    }, &armapimanagement.SubscriptionClientCreateOrUpdateOptions{Notify: nil,
        IfMatch: nil,
        AppType: nil,
    })

Question #1:
I want to create a brand new Subscription -- not Update an existing one. Given that, what should the <subscription-id> be? Can it be an arbitrary UUID that I create before calling NewClientFactory()?
Question #2:
Since I want to create a brand new Subscription, what do I pass in for the first 3 arguments to CreateOrUpdate()? It needs a resourceGroupName, a serviceName and an SID. What am I supposed to use for those?!?!? Those three values are used by CreateOrUpdate() to construct the following URL: urlPath := "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/subscriptions/{sid}"
